# What is the state of numerical fields[properties] in PHP

Tags: php, oop, yii

I am initially creating an object:

```
car{gearNumber,tyres}
```

Where the gearNumber, and tyres are car properties... and save it in database(mysql) without assigning any value to gearNumber, and tyres.

When I fetch the car object and try to increase the gear number nothing happens..the work around  would be to set default values(`0`) on object creation but I dont want to go back again to edit the car class since somehow php assign value on the fly...

Comment: set MySQL table values to default to 0 instead of null.

Comment: sure,i already did that and the strange thing is that nothing happens,it seems that php(or maybe caused by Yii) doesnt recognize zero as numerical value before if it is fetched as an object field until you operate some arithmetic on it,here is my scenario..i fetched the object car which probably fetch its values from  database {gearNumber,tyres} that are set to zero in database by default and try to to increment gearNumber like gearNumber++ and save it again and nothing happens..however if i do like gearNumber+1  the value changes,..i dont get where i doing things wrong now!thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without looking at the actual code, but it may happen that when retrieving the row from the DB an empty string (or a null value) is being placed in the properties of your object.

Regarding the workaround, there are many. Maybe the one you are looking for is to create a [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) that takes the gearNumber and tyres as parameters. That is the OO way of saying "if you want to create a car, then you must supply the gear number and the tyres".

HTH

Comment: $model->gearNumber=$model->gearnumber++;
$model->save();
after fetching it again nothing changes,but when i do the same thing with                                                                $model->gearNumber=$model->gearnumber+1;
$model->save(); it works fine

Comment: Honestly I don't know if that is a valid way of doing it. Maybe you are looking for `$model->gearNumber+=1`? You could also check the [assignment operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: It seems that you edited your answer while I was writing. Then I guess you found the answer yourself :)

Comment: thanks...i will consider the constructor,the reason i asked about this problem is that i constantly add new fields to class Car and i didnt want to go back there and add default value to any field since the framework{yii} reads fields from tables...

Comment: hey..i didnt find the the exact answer of what i was looking for but yours is better since i can use the constructor to initialize only the problematic fields...Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I don't know the specifics of yii, so I can't help there. The "found the answer yourself" was because you find the ++ issue. And yes, I think the constructor is well suited here, since it also conveys the right semantics. Glad to help :)